# Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique key prop

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to render 0-9 digits with either the list or the footer. Here is my code,

```
render(){
        var payments = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        payments.push(
            <Text>{i}</Text>
        )
    }

    return (
      <Content>
              {this.state.haveContent ? this.renderList() : this.renderFooter()}
         {payments}
      </Content>
        )
  }
}
```

But it turns out I keep having this warning and my first conditional statement is not working too. Any one can help me with this issue?

Comment: please provide the code for `renderlist `and `renderfooter` or the whole class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rendering an array and react requires that each component inside the array has a `key` attribute.

Update the text component with the key attribute

`for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    payments.push(
        <Text key={i.toString()}>{i}</Text>
    )
}`

read more about keys [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Comment: Actually using the index is _not_ recommended.  https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys

Comment: it was given as an example as the models props weren't mentioned